# How to create a formula using the range/argument referenced in a formula in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have tried searching for the answer to my question and have come up short. I don't know all the lingo so it could have been in front of me, but I didn't realize it and I passed it.

Simply what I am trying to do is to write an excel function (say `MAX`), and for the argument/range used in said function, I want to take it from the function in another cell or the cell above (say that function was `MIN`). It can be in VBA or a non-coding solution.

So what it would look like is:

Cell A1:

```
=MIN(C1:C100)
```

and Cell A2:

```
=MAX(CallRange(A1))
```

CallRange obviously being hypothetical/made up function.

EDIT:

Wow I am pleasantly surprised about the support on this site. I was thinking I might get at least one unrelated answer sometime in the next month or so, but all answers were relative and helpful.

Because I assumed I wouldn't get an answer for some time I created a work-around that has worked pretty well:

In my VBA macro I created to analyze a full worksheet of raw data, part of it creates this table with multiple Min, Max, Avg for data in a column for multiple columns (current, voltage, wattage, ambient). SO what I did was I coded the macro to create named ranges (Titled: Cdata, Vdata, Wdata, and Amb). I predefined all of the named rages to Offset a number of columns (Defined: `=OFFSET(Wdata,0,-1)`, -2, or -3) from Wdata, that which I would go in and define manually in the data.
So other than the predefined named ranges, the function I was originally asked about changed to:

Row 1: `=MIN(Amb)` `=MIN(Cdata)` `=MIN(Vdata)` `=MIN(Wdata)`

Row 2: `=MAX(Amb)` `=MAX(Cdata)` `=MAX(Vdata)` `=MAX(Wdata)`

Row 3: `=AVERAGE(Amb)` `=AVERAGE(Cdata)` `=AVERAGE(Vdata)` `=AVERAGE(Wdata)`

So in the end, the only thing I would have to do is define Wdata once I open the worksheet.

This works well, but I'm still open to any other solutions.

Thanks everyone,
Zac

Comment: can't be done with formulas but you can put the cell range itself in a cell as a string and reference that using INDIRECT to convert the string to a valid range reference.

Answer (score 0):

OK Assuming that the function has the same argument list and there is only one pair of brackets, you can use the FORMULATEXT function to get the formula and then use text functions to extract the arguments (by finding the brackets). Finally use INDIRECT to convert to a reference.

Example like what you showed above:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VBA Excel cells are often referenced by *offset* to the current cell, for instance:

```
myValue = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).value
```

will refer to the cell -1 *row* (up) and in the *same column* as your current selected cell.

For more reading see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-relative-to-other-cells